# Azure WebSites - Can't Scale Sites Individually (New Web Hosting Plan Groups)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Just this morning, the management portal for Azure WebSites no longer lets me scale individually.  It looks as though all my websites have been grouped into a "Web Hosting Plan".  And now when I create a new web site, I have to choose a plan.  I've looked around and I can't find any information on "Web Hosting Plans" -- is this some preview function that got pushed out early?  Does anyone know how to create a new plan and switch a website to it?

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The ability to move a site to a new or existing Web Hosting Plan has finally been added to the Azure Portal! Note: this is only on the "new" Azure Portal preview site: https://portal.azure.com/

Navigate to the site that you want to move to another Web Hosting Plan and click on the 3 dots for "more" options:

[image: More options]

Then, choose "Web Hosting Plan" from the menu:

[image: Web hosting plans menu]

A window is presented with the option to choose an existing Web Hosting Plan, or create a new one:

[image: Choose web hosting plan]

Comment: Wow, this is documented *nowhere* that I can find.  I got massively overbilled because Visual Studio puts every new website into a separate hosting plan without telling you and I could not figure out any way to consolidate my sites.  Even MS support told me that it wasn't possible.  I'm glad I stumbled across this!

Answer (score 7):

This article explains the concept of Web Hosting Plan and has an example of how to move site between Web Hosting Plans.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

(Search for "Question: How can I move a Site to a different Web Hosting Plan?")

Unfortunately right now this can be done via API and PowerShell only. The team is looking into adding this capability in Azure portal.

Comment: I was about to cross post from your answer in the MSDN forum...  Thanks for the info.

Comment: The referenced article is great, but it assumes you have a second hosting plan already.  I can't seem to create one via the API, and Google has failed.  Do you have any insight on how to create the container to move a site *to*?

Comment: The answer from kdenney is now the right answer. Go to the new portal.

Answer (score 0):

Azure clubs websites into Hosting Plans, so if you scale one website it will actually be scaling the hosting plan and all websites in that plan will scale up. This is actually stupid but thats how they thought it through.

As stated above you can create multiple plans as per your requirements and club websites into those plan from the new Azure Management portal only.